# IFC - Representation of triangle mesh

Tags: ifc

What is the best way to represent a simple triangle mesh in IFC?

This seems to be a way:
`IfcFaceBasedSurfaceModel -> IfcConnectedFaceSet -> IfcFace -> IfcFaceBound -> IfcPolyLoop -> IfcCartesianPoint`

However, seems to be a little complex since the functionality of `IfcFace` and `IfcPolyLoop` exceed those one needs for a simple triangle mesh.

Any other options?

Answer (score 3):

Since IFC4 there is also the geometric representation type [IfcTriangulatedFaceSet](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/IFC4/final/html/schema/ifcgeometricmodelresource/lexical/ifctriangulatedfaceset.htm), which represents surfaces as tesselations of triangles, using a point list and an index list for the triangles.