# create custom polygon wall using xbim library

Tags: c#, ifc, xbim

I try to make ifc wall using some polygon points and save to ifc file.

I found some approach and try that, but it does not work.

- https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimGeometry/issues/117
- [IFC - Representation of triangle mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819408/ifc-representation-of-triangle-mesh)

here is my code:

```
private static void CreateCustomPolygonWall(IfcStore model)
{
    using (var txn = model.BeginTransaction("Create Custom Polygon"))
    {
        List<double[]> points = new List<double[]>();
        points.Add(new double[] { 0, 0, 0 });
        points.Add(new double[] { 100, 0, 0 });
        points.Add(new double[] { 100, 100, 0 });

        var list = new List<IfcCartesianPoint>();
        foreach (var coordinates in points.Select(p => p.Select(x => new IfcLengthMeasure(x))))
        {
            var point = model.Instances.New<IfcCartesianPoint>();
            point.Coordinates.AddRange(coordinates);
            list.Add(point);
        }

        var faceSet = model.Instances.New<Xbim.Ifc4.TopologyResource.IfcConnectedFaceSet>();
        List<int[]> indexes = new List<int[]>();
        indexes.Add(new int[] { 0, 1, 2 });
        foreach (var t in indexes)
        {
            var polyLoop = model.Instances.New<Xbim.Ifc4.TopologyResource.IfcPolyLoop>();
            polyLoop.Polygon.AddRange(t.Select(k => list[k]));

            var bound = model.Instances.New<Xbim.Ifc4.TopologyResource.IfcFaceBound>();
            bound.Bound = polyLoop;

            var face = model.Instances.New<Xbim.Ifc4.TopologyResource.IfcFace>();
            face.Bounds.Add(bound);
            faceSet.CfsFaces.Add(face);
        }

        var surface = model.Instances.New<IfcFaceBasedSurfaceModel>();
        surface.FbsmFaces.Add(faceSet);

        txn.Commit();
    }
}
```

and if I save to ifc file following the code, the file has polygon points that I describe. but it is not showing any ifc viewer.

```
#23=IFCCARTESIANPOINT((0.,0.,0.));
#24=IFCCARTESIANPOINT((100.,0.,0.));
#25=IFCCARTESIANPOINT((100.,100.,0.));
```

so how can I create a polygon wall and save it to ifc file using xbim library?

any hint?

best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create more than just the geometry to create an IFC file which other viewers would process and display. [Here](https://docs.xbim.net/examples/proper-wall-in-3d.html) is a working example of 3D wall creation. If you want to define the wall as any arbitrary profile, you would replace `IfcRectangleProfileDef` in the example with other [profile definition](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/HTML/link/ifcprofiledef.htm), likely [IfcArbitraryClosedProfileDef](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/HTML/link/ifcarbitraryclosedprofiledef.htm) with `OuterCurve` being [IfcPolyline](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/HTML/link/ifcpolyline.htm).